# VBScript: Function visibility inside a Class with identical property name

Tags: class, oop, object, vbscript, asp-classic

Given that we have a script

```
Option Explicit

Class CClass
    Private m_date

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        m_date = CDate("1970-01-01 00:00:00")
    End Sub

    Public Function Foo()
        Dim d : d = Date()
        WScript.Echo "d is " & FormatDateTime(d, vbGeneralDate)
    End Function

    Public Property Get Date()
        Date = m_date
    End Property

    Public Property Let Date(p_date)
        m_date = CDate(p_date)
    End Property

End Class

Dim obj : Set obj = NEW CClass
Call obj.Foo()
```

How can class function CClass.Foo() call built-in VBScript function Date() without the property CClass.Date interfering?

My current solution is to introduce a dummy Date_() function which can be called instead. But that just seems wrong. I'm thinking there should be some way to specify that we want to call something outside the class scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am almost positive that there is no way to do what you're asking in VBScript.

But even if you *could* figure out a way to do this, you really *shouldn't*. You need to choose names for your own functions that don't conflict with the names of built-in functions. Anything else is completely unmaintainable for a dynamic scripting language like VBScript.

Pick a different name for your `Date` property. Preferably something *more descriptive*: what kind of date does that property return? What does the date refer to? How is it likely to be used? Whatever you do, don't rename it to `Date_`—that's not any better.

Comment: I'm sure you're right on that it'll never work. What comes to property naming, I didn't want to repeat the name of the class in the property: e.g. class is CEvent, property is EventDate; seemed redundant at best. What you suggest seems reasonable, though. Maybe I should just endure it. I'll give some time to others to raise opinnions and mark you accepted, if nothing relevant turns up.

Comment: @msk: If that's the case, I would definitely go for `EventDate`. (Or something even more descriptive, like `ScheduledDate`.) You're trading a tiny bit of redundancy for clarity, as well as eliminating the possibility of hiding built-in methods. If the typing really bothers you, my best suggestion is to find an old copy of VB 6 and take advantage of its IntelliSense (auto-completion) functionality. It works just as well for VBScript code, even if you never use the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You can call it from inside the class like:
`Dim d : d = me.Date()`

`Me` in VBScript is the same as you use `This` in Javascript for example

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I definitely didn't want to call the class property.

Comment: Ah, OK. Yes, I misunderstood. You can do dirty hacks with the ExecuteGlobal() statement and global variables. Or passthru-functions outside your class that just pass the result from Date(), but it won't get more beautiful. So, I have to agree with Cody Gray.

Answer (score 0):

Too late to the party, but there is a solution using `eval` function.
[see eval function docs for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094(v=vs.84).aspx)

```
Class CClass
    Private m_date

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        m_date = CDate("1970-01-01 00:00:00")
    End Sub

    Public Function Foo()
        Dim d : d = eval("Date()")
        WScript.Echo "d is " & FormatDateTime(d, vbGeneralDate)
    End Function

    Public Property Get Date()
        Date = m_date
    End Property

    Public Property Let Date(p_date)
        m_date = CDate(p_date)
    End Property

End Class

Dim obj : Set obj = NEW CClass
Call obj.Foo()
```